# IE issue with :hover

Tags: css

I am trying to figure out why my CSS does nopt work in IE (v.9).

I have the following CSS:

```
#cq div:hover {
   background-color: #fff;
   cursor: pointer
}
```

and HTML

```
<div id="cq">
    <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
</div>
```

It works fine in all other browsers.

Comment: adding class to child divs will solve this issue.

Comment: I think IE is very strict give `semicolon (;)` after `cursor: pointer` and check again.

Comment: @Salil: That's definitely not true, but it won't hurt.

Comment: @WesleyMurch i have faced like this situation. It will hurt if you miss semicolon(;). I am not sure. but it is a problem in any one the famous browsers.

Comment: It works fine for me in IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/bJhnx/

Comment: when i parse your css it is looking like this in IE #cq > div:hover. but not in @WesleyMurch sample. better verify your css again.

Comment: Tried ; at the end of class definition -- did not work. And honestly this should not be an issue. When you optimize CSS, the last semicolons are always removed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that your page is running in Quirks mode. Try changing your doctype to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

More on browser modes:
http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/

Comment: @santa Did you clear your cache etc.? In the IE9 developer tools, if I change the document mode to anything except quirks mode, then it works as expected. Your demo doesn't seem to have changed?

Comment: You're right. Apparently there's some logic on the page and it may display two different headers. Earlier I updated the wrong one. Fixed the correct one and indeed it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine. try to change background color

```
#cq div:hover {
background-color: red;
 cursor: pointer;
}

<div id="cq">
<div>item</div>
<div>item</div>
 </div>
```

here the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p7kLc/)

Comment: Yep, it seem to work in your demo. There might be some conflict in my particular case... still digging.